# AD Server Connection Probem

Tags: linux, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp

Ok so i have a Linux server handling the DHCP, and FTP server i have and Network Shares. Then i have a Server (Windows R2) with just the AD. None of the client computers can connect to the Domain. The way i fixed this before, was the DHCP was on the Windows Server, back then when i had it on there. Today i moved the DHCP to the Linux computer and now, like stated before, clients cant connect. I want to know if moving the DHCP was the error? When using an AD, does the same computer have to run the DHCP? or is there something else thats not letting the clients connect?

```
Im subnetting my network:
Scope is 192.168.1.0 /28
Range: 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.14 (leaving 192.168.1.0 as the Network, 192.168.1.1 as the       Router/DNS/Default Gateway, 192.168.1.15 as the broadcast address)
Server addresses:
Linux: 192.168.1.6
Windows: 192.168.1.2
rest are for clients, i am thinking of changing the ip of my linux server to 1.3, just to have them close together...
```

Comment: Do your clients get IP addresses? Is the DHCP server handing out the right DNS server addresses?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, i have tested the clients and all of them get an ip and DNS is forwarded to the router. I might make the Linux handle DNS too but thats later, im concerned about the AD. So yea all computers have internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the reason none of your Windows clients can talk to the domain is that you are serving them the wrong DNS server address from your DHCP server.

You need to provide the DNS addresses of the DNS server(s) in your AD domain. Which, in an installation this small, is almost certainly running on your domain controller. In particular, you should *not* hand out any DNS server address that isn't a DNS server in the domain.

Comment: so i should make my Windows Server the DNS server? and have the linux server forward DNS to that computer? If i understood correctly

Comment: Right. If it's the only DNS server that's part of the domain, then use only that.

Comment: ok... i might need some help on that one, i got pissed off at windows for the confusion it makes when configuring this kidn of stuff, this past week ive been "+1 for Linux" on things like FTP and DHCP so thats y i moved everything. Have any links to help me set up my DNS?

Comment: It should already _be_ set up. If you unconfigured it, then perhaps you should ask a new question...and don't sysadmin in anger.

Comment: i unconfigured it foolishly yes, and no i didnt mean like i was throwing punches but like... just wondering _why?_ does windows do this... when i do the same thing on Linux and its 50x much easier

Comment: Don't blame Windows. I could rant and rave about how confusing Linux is... but only because I don't know Linux.

Comment: @xR34P3Rx Judging by the quality of research done here and the obvious lack of knowledge and research on your part, I doubt the problem is Windows.

Comment: i understand, i guess i just havent completely learned windows server all the way. Over time i find myself to be more of a linux person, every one has their preference.